# I can't put the Tk widgets on the windows

Tags: python, class, tkinter, extending

I am extending the tk widgets to make a gui app. The problem is that I can put them on the main window without an error, but they are not visible. I have called the super constructor, but it still not showing up. i even tried to use ai to debug it, but that din't work to, so I am asking for help

```
from tkinter import *
from functions import *

class InventoryLabel (Label):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.config(text=transform_data())


class FirstFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.configure(bg="red")
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        InventoryLabel(self)


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1250x950")
        self.title("Inventory")
        text_frame = FirstFrame(self)
        self.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never called `.grid()` (or other geometry management method) on your `InventoryLabel` instance.

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the window.

That happens because you're doing self.mainloop() in the class itself, so the other elements doesn't have time to load.

It's like that:

1. creating the class, and then opens the window
2. adds the elements - but window is already open

Do that:

```
from tkinter import *
from functions import *

class InventoryLabel (Label):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.config(text=transform_data())


class FirstFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, **kwargs)
        self.configure(bg="red")
        self.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        InventoryLabel(self)


class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("1250x950")
        self.title("Inventory")
        self.text_frame = FirstFrame(self)

window = Window()

window.mainloop()
```

And hopefully it would work.

If you want to add the elemnts **AFTER** the window is created, you can do window.after(1, function)

Comment: This does not solve OP issue which is caused by not calling any layout function on the instance of `InventoryLabel` as said in the comment.